# How do I introduce a new variable in a trigonometric equation?

Tags: output-formatting, algebraic-manipulation, trigonometry

I have the trigonometric equation
\begin{equation*}
\sin^8 x +  2\cos^8 x  -\dfrac{1}{2}\cos^2 2x + 4\sin^2 x= 0.
\end{equation*}
By putting $t = \cos 2x$, I have
\begin{equation*}
\dfrac{3}{16} t^4+ \dfrac{1}{4}t^3 + \dfrac{5}{8}t^2 -\dfrac{7}{4}t + \dfrac{35}{16} = 0.
\end{equation*}
 How do I tell Mathematica to do that?
Mathematica code is

```
Sin[x]^8 + 2 Cos[x]^8 - 1/2 Cos[2 x]^2 + 4 Sin[x]^2 == 0
```

Comment: If you supply your terms in Mathematica syntax as well, that would make working with them much more comfortable.

Comment: With Maple, I used the following code
restart; sort(simplify(algsubs(1-sin(x)^2=cos(x)^2, sin(x)^8+ 2*cos(x)^8  -1/2*cos(2*x)^2 + 4*sin(x)^2), {expand(cos(2*x))=t}));

Comment: I meant: Please format your (LaTeX) expressions in Mathematica syntax so we can copy and paste easily.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `TrigExpand` to expand all trigonometric functions to fundamental forms and then `Eliminate` solves the rest

```
eq1 = Sin[x]^8 + 2 Cos[x]^8 - 1/2 Cos[2 x]^2 + 4 Sin[x]^2 == 0;
eq2 = t == Cos[2 x]

Eliminate[TrigExpand[{eq1, eq2}], x]
```

Answer (score 12):

One way to do this is:

```
Sin[x]^8 + 2 Cos[x]^8 - 1/2 Cos[2 x]^2 + 4 Sin[x]^2 == 0 /. 
  Solve[t == Cos[2 x], x] //FullSimplify // Expand // Union // Column // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

It gives exactly your answer if you get rid of your denominator 16 (multiply both sides of your equation by 16).

This will also work with more complex substitutions (for example `t == Cos[x^2 - 1]` ) when you can get multiple results:

```
Sin[x]^8 + 2 Cos[x]^8 - 1/2 Cos[2 x]^2 + 4 Sin[x]^2 == 0 /. 
Solve[t == Cos[x^2 - 1], x]//FullSimplify//Expand//Union //Column // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

A bit different approach :

```
Simplify @ TrigReduce[ Sin[x]^8 + 2 Cos[x]^8 - 1/2 Cos[2 x]^2 + 4 Sin[x]^2 == 0
/. Solve[ t == Cos[2 x], x, InverseFunctions -> True][[1]]]
```

> ```
> 35 + 10 t^2 + 4 t^3 + 3 t^4 == 28 t
> ```

or using `Eliminate` :

```
Eliminate[ TrigToExp[{ Sin[x]^8 + 2 Cos[x]^8 - 1/2 Cos[2 x]^2 + 4 Sin[x]^2 == 0,
                      t == Cos[2 x]}], x, InverseFunctions -> True] // 
PolynomialForm[#, TraditionalOrder -> True] &
```

> ```
> 3 t^4 + 4 t^3 + 10 t^2 - 28 t == -35
> ```

Answer (score 1):

First plot the trigonometric equation:

```
Plot[Sin[x]^8 + 2 Cos[x]^8 - 1/2 Cos[2 x]^2 + 4 Sin[x]^2 == 0, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

You will see that there are no (real) solutions. Is this what you expect?

Comment: No. I only want as I asked.