# How to make algebraic substitutions?

Tags: symbolic, algebraic-manipulation

I would like to simplify complicated expressions by defining some variable that is a combination of other variables that appear in the expression, but without eliminating the original variables.

As a simple example, I would like to convert

```
a^2 + a*b^2 + b
```

to

```
a*c + b
```

by introducing the relation

```
c == a + b^2
```

I saw [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11178/how-do-i-introduce-a-new-variable-in-a-trigonometric-equation), but the answers require that one variable be eliminated.  The best expressions I could get with those strategies are

```
b - b^2 c + c^2
a*c - Sqrt[-a + c]
a*c + Sqrt[-a + c]
```

depending on whether I eliminate `a` or `b`, but these are not meaningfully simpler than the original expression.  Is there any way to introduce a new variable without eliminating one of the dependent variables in the expression?  If it matters, I have Mathematica 10.3.

Comment: Check 'PolynomialReduce'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Simplify[a^2 + a*b^2 + b, b^2 == c - a]

(*  b + a c  *)
```

Or

```
a^2 + a*b^2 + b /. b^2 -> c - a // Simplify

(*  b + a c  *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Also

```
Simplify[a^2 + a*b^2 + b, Assumptions -> {c == a + b^2}]
```

works.

Comment: In `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` it is not necessary to to use the `Assumptions ->` before the assumptions.